# Getting the Row Matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a n*n matrix into its respective row matrix in Matlab. How to achieve this ?

For example assume the original matrix is

```
7.0000   26.0000    6.0000   60.0000   78.5000

1.0000   29.0000   15.0000   52.0000   74.3000

11.0000    56.0000    8.0000   20.0000  104.3000
```

and I want to get the output as

7.0000   26.0000    6.0000   60.0000   78.5000   1.0000   29.0000   15.0000

52.0000   74.3000    11.0000   56.0000    8.0000   20.0000  104.3000

which is the row matrix.

Answer (score 3):

As you want to reshape it into a vector, `reshape` might be a bit overkill, as you can just use linear indexing.

```
A = randi(10,5,5); %Create some matrix
B=A.'; %SLOW
B = B(:).'; %matrix -> vector conversion
```

On the other hand, the speed of the matrix -> vector conversion does not really matter as it is the initial transpose which is slow, which you'll need for any method, see e.g. Phil's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is:

```
Anew = reshape(Aold',1,numel(Aold));
```

Of particular importance is that you need to use the transpose of `Aold`.

Comment: In before Luis Mendo: "Matlab's `'` is not transpose; `.'` is." :D

Comment: That's purely being pendantic for pedantic's sake.

Comment: If ‘Aold’ is complex your solution is technically wrong without throwing an error. So yes, it is pedantic, but try to imagine to find that error.

Comment: I realize that, however the OP's matrix is clearly real, and my solution clearly deals with that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
reshape(A, 1, []);
```

where A is your matrix. For example:

```
A = rand(5,5);
b = reshape(A, 1, []);
```

will give you a 1x25 matrix.

Comment: This is not the vector he is interested in, see Phil's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your original matrix is A (which has 15 elements)

```
A = [7.0000   26.0000    6.0000   60.0000   78.5000;

1.0000   29.0000   15.0000   52.0000   74.3000;

11.0000    56.0000    8.0000   20.0000  104.3000]
```

Now what you need is to reshape A to become a row vector.

```
reshape(A,1,[]) % Here 1 means you need one row, and [] means you need is as vector
```

If you want column vector you may use the following

```
reshape(A,[],1) % this gives a column vector
```

However, according to your objective the following code will do the job

```
A = [7.0000   26.0000    6.0000   60.0000   78.5000;

1.0000   29.0000   15.0000   52.0000   74.3000;

11.0000    56.0000    8.0000   20.0000  104.3000];

reshape(A,1,[])
```

The output will be

```
ans =

7.0000    1.0000   11.0000   26.0000   29.0000   56.0000    6.0000   15.0000    8.0000   60.0000   52.0000   20.0000   78.5000   74.3000  104.3000
```

For detailed information, type the following in the command window

```
help reshape
```

Comment: As I also mentioned on @Ryan answer, this is not what OP is asking. The vector should be `[7, 26, ... ]` not `[7, 1, ...]`.

Comment: Yes, I want the vector to be [7, 26, ... ]. How to get it ?

Comment: @N.Chandimali , You use either mine or Phil's solution